# Wordpress and Next.js hosting on AWS

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, amazon-ec2, next.js

Currently we have deployed Wordpress on the AWS Lightsail serving on somedomain.com and have our Next.js application on the EC2 instance behind Nginx on anotherdomain.com.
Our goal is to serve both the WordPress and Next.js on the somedomain.com for SEO purposes where landing page and few other pages will be served on Wordpress and other links would be served by our Next.js application. How can we approach this?

Eg. somedomain.com -> WP landing page
somedomain.com/abc -> Next.js app

I am expecting an AWS architecture/approach where we could host both Wordpress and Next.js under the same URL for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the [path-based routing feature](https://www.boardinfinity.com/blog/path-based-routing-on-aws-alb/) of AWS application load balancer (ALB).

1. You can configure all incoming HTTP requests starting with `/api/*` to hit a target group that re-routes to the auto-scaling group / EC2 instances running your API server(s)
2. Then create a wildcard path to route all other paths to the wordpress server.
3. You will then be able to serve all the incoming requests under CNAME of your desired domain name of choice.

[image]